# Bug Printing List of Arrays in Java After Sorting

Tags: java

Im working on a project that consist of creating an array based on a number input, and then assigning int values through inputs. It then runs through a bubble sort to sort the values in increasing order. I am having trouble on the printing for this of all things. I use Eclipse as my IDE and I can't really make much of what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Ex07_18 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Prompt user to enter the numbers of integers to be entered
        System.out.print("Enter the number of integers:");
        final int NUM_OF_INTS = input.nextInt();

        int[] numbers = new int[NUM_OF_INTS];

        // Input the numbers into an array
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_INTS; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
            numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
        }// end for

        // Bubble sort the array
        bubbleSort(numbers);

        // Print out the integers
        printList(numbers);

        input.close();          
    }// end main

    public static void bubbleSort(int[] list) {

        int listLength = list.length;
        int temp;
        boolean is_sorted;
        for (int i= 0; i < listLength; i++) {

            is_sorted = true;

            for (int j = 1; j < listLength; j++) {

                if (list[j - 1] > list[j]) {
                    temp = list[j - 1];
                    list[j - 1] = list[j];
                    list[j] = temp;
                    is_sorted = false;
                } // end if
            } // end for

            if (is_sorted) break;

        } // end for



    }// end bubbleSort

    public static void printList(int[] numbers) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++ ) {

            // Print the numbers
            System.out.print(numbers[i] + "    ");

        }// end for
    }// end printList



}// end Ex07_18
```

Comment: Everything seems to work fine, you just need to change `i < numbers.length - 1` to `i < numbers.length` in `printList`

Answer (score 1):

In for loop in printList method you iterate through number.length - 1 elements instead of number.length elements. Your printList method should look like this:

```
public static void printList(int[] numbers) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i ) {

        // Print the numbers
        System.out.print(numbers[i] + "    ");

    }// end for
}// end printList
```

Answer (score 0):

In your printList function, you are setting the comparison condition incorrectly,

```
public static void printList(int[] numbers) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++ ) { //should be i <= numbers.length - 1

        // Print the numbers
        System.out.print(numbers[i] + "    ");

    }// end for
}// end printList
```